# Discord.js - Detect reply from a certain message within 1 minute

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

### What I Want to Archive...

I am trying to create a guess command handler to my discord bot. It will pick a random item from an array and the user, by following some hints, will need to guess the selected word within 1 minute.

### Problem

The command handler only allows to run a specific code once, so it will not detect if the user reply. Because of that I cannot detect if an user replied to a certain message from the bot within a certain time.

### Code

```js
// Copyright © 2022 <copyright holders>

// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the “Software”), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED “AS IS”, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.


const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { prefix, colors } = require("./../utils/config.json");
const embedColor = colors.default;
const embedError = colors.error;

module.exports = {
  name: "guess",
  description: "Find a secret animal by following the hints to get reputation.",
  aliases: ["?", "h"],
  usage: "[prefix] + ping",
  guildOnly: false,
  args: false,
  slash: true,
  permissions: {
    bot: [],
    user: [],
  },
  execute: async (message, args, client) => {
    const { commands } = message.client;

    function question() {
      // Sending message

      const animals = ["pig", "elephant", "shark", "dog", "cat", "lion", "wolf", "bee", "snake", "bird"];

      const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * animals.length);
      const random_choice = (animals[random]);


//    msg2 = message.channel.send("See or Change?");
//    if (msg2.type === 'REPLY')
//      console.log(msg1.content);

      let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
      message.channel.send(`Are you sure to delete all data? \`YES\` / \`NO\``).then(() => {
        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
          max: 1,
          time: 10000,
          errors: ['time']
        })
        .then(message => {
          message = message.first();
          if (message.content.toLowerCase() == random_choice) {
            message.channel.send(`Got it right`)
          } else {
            message.channel.send('The Animal was: `' + random_choice + '`!')
          }
        })
        .catch(collected => {
          message.channel.send('Timeout');
        });
      })
    }

    let { channel, reference: reply } = message

    const cmdHelpEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("**PING**")
      .setDescription(`Hey, ` + message.author.username + `! I am ready to play guess game`)
      .setColor(embedColor)
      .addFields(
        {
          name: 'How to play?',
          value: 'This game is simple, I will select a random animal and give you 3 hints. You just need to find the correct animal to win reputation. To answer reply to this message, within 1 minute'
        }, {
          name: '\u200B',
          value: '**RULES**'
        }, {
          name: 'Rule 1:',
          value: 'No Cheating',
          inline: true
        },
        {
          name: 'Rule 2:',
          value: 'Have fun!',
          inline: true
        },
      );

    message.channel.send({
      embeds: [cmdHelpEmbed],
    });

    var delayInMilliseconds = 5000; // 5 seconds

    setTimeout(function() {
      question();
    }, delayInMilliseconds);
  },
};
```

Comment: Can you explain what goes wrong here with more details ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because of the way you defined your collector.

Instead of:

```
message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ['time']})
```

Do:

```
message.channel.awaitMessages({filter, max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ['time']})
```